# Django - TemplateDoesNotExist at

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm stucked on this problem. I've checked many advices here and on google but no way to get rid of this error.

It seems that `Django` does not check `app/templates/*` directory. It should be checked automatically, shouldn't it?

My `settings.py`:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'sekret-key-goes-here'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'chart_tools',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'gw_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'gw_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And here is the structure of the project:

[image]

Here is the error, as you can see, it does not check templates directory...

[image]

Comment: Set `'DIRS': ['templates']`

Comment: You should probably change your `SECRET_KEY` now that you've posted it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Chris Thanks Chris, I will.

Comment: @gtlambert , that's unnecessary in this situation. The `app_directories.Loader` will automatically search in the `templates` directory of each installed app. Relevant docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `gw_app` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`...

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'chart_tools',
    'gw_app',
)
```

Comment: Thank you man. Sometimes you are trying everything and finally it's the most obvious option :)